# MacBook Air Display Color Temperature Changes After Logging In

Tags: macbook-pro, display, color, temperature

Since I can remember, my MacBook Air's Display has been behaving strangely. Every time I log in, the color temperature of the display changes to a warmer tone and it's very noticeable and annoying. I tried to fix it by reinstalling macOS High Sierra, but the problem is still there so the problem is at a system level, instead of my settings, maybe?

I'll inset two photos where you can see the before (bluish tone) and after (yellowish tone).

How can I prevent my display from changing to that warmer tone?

Display with bluish tone (original):
[image: Display with bluish tone (original)]

Display showing yellowish tone:
[image: Display showing yellowish tone]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue
Idk if you guys are still having the problem two years later, but for others who are try turning off **True Tone** under **Display**.
If the problem is still happening after that I have no clue.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal.

When macOS is booting it will access your settings and see if you have specified the color temperature. Or enabled Night Shift.

If you have enabled FileVault this change will happen after you are logged in.

I think you need to put Color Temperature on Less Warm instead of in the center. And/Or turn off the Night Shift option.

[image: System Preferences -> Night Shift]

Comment: I had Night Shift turned off, and I change the color temperature to less warm, but when I restarted my MacBook, it still did the color temperature change... So If Color LCD is the default color setting, why does it "changes" after logging in, it's like the warm temperature is Color LCD, but the original setting before logging in is other; and if I change the color profile, first is the "original" color temperature, then it loads the "Color LCD" (I guess is the warmer setting), and then it changes to the Color Profile I change it to...

Comment: So what is that "original" cooler temperature it has before getting into the account (and in recovery mode as well), and how can I made it the default so it doesn't make any weird warmer change after logging in?

Comment: Do you have a custom profile applied? Maybe from a screen calibration... X-Rite, Datacolor etc? They tend to apply last minute before the desktop appears [I have auto-login enabled so I don't see the sign-in window to say exactly at what point it may happen]

Comment: Before reinstalling macOS I had ProPhoto RGB Calibrated, but now I have the Color LCD profile by default in the clean installation of macOS.

Comment: So is there any way of making the OS leave the color temperature as it is before logging in, instead of changing it to that "Color LCD" warm color temperature?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It changes to a warmer color temp everytime my computer goes to sleep and I have to log in again. I have Night Shift off permanently and color temp is set all the way to the left to Less Warm.

What I do is open Display settings, and navigate to Night Shift. I quickly turn it on manually and then disable it again. That seems to reset the color temp so that my whites are white and blues are blue.

This is a pretty big issue if you want to edit photos or videos on your macbook, like many do...

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to find a solution to our problem. If you do, please let me know!